# Rspec test not passing in my posts controller, 'expected response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <200: OK> '

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want it to redirect to the user page for the just created post.
But, I'm facing the following error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to user_path(user.id)

       Expected response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <200: OK>
       Response body:
```

Here is my posts_controller_spec.rb

```
describe "POST #create" do
    context "parameter is reasonable" do
      let(:valid_attributes) {
        FactoryBot.attributes_for(:post)
      }

      it "redirect user page" do
        post :create, params: { user_id: user.id, post: valid_attributes }
        expect(response).to redirect_to user_path(user.id)
      end
    end
  end
```

My factories/users.rb

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :admin_user, class: User do
    name 'Alice'
    email 'test@gmail.com'
    intro 'rubyなう'
    password 'Testtesttest'
    admin true
  end

  factory :user, class: User do
    name 'Bob'
    email 'test@gmail.com'
    intro 'rubyなう'
    password 'Testtesttest'
  end
end
```

My factories/posts.rb

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :post, class: Post do
    content 'a' * 140
    image Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'app/assets/images/tokyo.jpg'))
    user
  end
end
```

My posts_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

    if @post.save
      flash[:success] = 'succeed in posting'
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `redirect_to user_path(current_user)` and then run the spec? 

Comment: Are you sure `@post` is valid? use a gem like byebug, add a `byebug` line right above the `if @post.save` line and inspect the `@post` value.

Comment: Might be a similar issue to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32386685/expected-response-to-be-a-redirect-but-was-200

Comment: @AliIlman I've tried it, but the result didn't change

Comment: @arieljuod I've tried it. Then, the result was as follows `"Image can't be blank", "Image Failed to manipulate with rmagick, maybe it is not an image?"`

Comment: @AliIlman thank you for telling me something similar